# How do I remove hyperlink color on visited if navbar "inverts" on hover?

Tags: html, css, colors

I am creating navbar. Transparent by default, but a certain color(including text/hyperlinks) once hovered over it. I can't seem to find a way to remove purple color from visited hyperlinks. Tried `:visited` and reformatting to make sure everything is as DRY as a beginner can make it be.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="topnav" id="Topnav">
        <a href="#Shop" class="active">Shop</a>
        <a href="#ourstory">Our Story</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </a>
      </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 6rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
}

.topnav:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: red; /* Hyperlinks supposed to inherit this color when hovering navbar*/
}
.topnav a {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Poppins,Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I was thinking of using `&&` and "IF" statement to check hover state in JS to hook it up, but there must be a css-pure solution...

P.S. Don't mind the colors, it's for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets the links blue whether visited or not - and sets the links red on `.topnav` hover whether the links are visited or not.

```
.topnav a {
 color: blue;
}

.topnav:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```